# Trying to show other side of one-to-one relationship in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a page that displays all the countries in the world and at the bottom of each are hyperlinks to all the bordering countries. In the API I'm using they are listed at their "alpha3Code" a 3 character long identifier for the country (Columbia - COL). I want to be able to have the alpha3Code translated into the full name with the countryLookup function. I can't seem to get just the name out of it. Here is this page running:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwfMD.png)
I attempted to add .name at the end of countryLookup(border) but there was then nothing in brackets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
export default {
  props: {
    country: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      countryByCode: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...
    countryLookup(code) {
      return this.countryByCode.filter(country => country.alpha3Code.includes(code));
    }
  },
  // computed: {
  //   countryLookup() {
  //     return this.countryByCode.filter(country => {
  //       return this.code.some(code => country.alpha3Code.includes(code));
  //   });
  //   }
  // },
  created() {
    CountryService.getCountryByCode()
      .then(response => {
        this.countryByCode = response.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
}
```

```html
<li v-for="border in country.borders" v-bind:key="border">
      <a href="#" @click="clearSearch" v-scroll-to="{ el: '#' + border }">{{ border }} - ({{ countryLookup(border) }})</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot it looks like you have an array of objects being returned. You would not be able to get `.name` because it is an array not an object being returned. If you want just the country name you might need to display it as:

```
{{ border[0].name }}
```

Comment: so the whole thing would look like this: {{ countryLookup(border[0]).name }} ? This is giving me empty brackets - ()

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data returned from response.data?

Comment: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …] Looks like this with console.log(response.data)

Comment: https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=alpha3Code;name this is the call I'm making.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
function search(nameKey, myArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i].alpha3Code === nameKey) {
        return myArray[i];
      }
    }
  }
```

This worked perfectly after putting countryLookup(border).name I don't think I was searching the array properly